# Setting up kerberos using ambari

Tags: kerberos

I am trying to set up kerberos on hortonworks hadoop platform on RHEL6.x and while settting up permission s i come across following error

```
chown ambari:ambari /etc/security/keytabs/ambari.keytab
chown: invalid user: `ambari:ambari'
```

how should i eliminate this error.